# field constant and @override

Tags: android, eclipse, overriding, field

Im trying to elminate all errors for an android app developed using Eclipse..

```
     "run_buton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbtn_runtoggle);
     run_buton.setOnClickListener(this);
     rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtn_ch1);
     rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtn_ch2);"
```

These are part of my code in the .java file in the src file...however there are errors..eclipse says that tbtn_runtoggle,rbtn_ch1, rbtn.ch2 cannot be resolved or it is not a field...so i use the quick fix and make them into a field...- -however it's still not work..i dont know what is happenening...and im just responsible for eliminating all errors...- -the codes are not written by myself..

and may I ask what is the use of @override..
it tells me "public void  onClick(View v){" must override a superclass method..so it suggests me to remove @override...but still gets error...why..???

Comment: need more insight of your code there. Not very clear where and what? you should paste a code with your onClick and where it's defined and located and what your class implements.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Make sure Java Compiler Version is set to 1.6 @Override annotation was introduced in 1.6 which means that you are overriding a method from a super class.
It looks like your Resource file "R" is not getting generated.
Try to clean the project and build again.

Comment: sorry...but how to make sure??

Comment: Nope Rajdeep DUa, @Override was not introduced in 1.6 bu t 1.5 you directions having nothing do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as per my suggestion, it is not good to remove that line. you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors. Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.